# Write back buffer in lpc

Tags: arm7

I was reading the **Lpc2148 Manual** and in the Static Ram section I came across

> **Write back buffer**

The **SRAM** controller incorporates a **write-back buffer** in order to prevent CPU stalls
during back-to-back writes. The write-back buffer always holds the last data sent by
software to the SRAM. This data is only written to the SRAM when another write is
requested by software.(the data is only written to the SRAM when software does another
write). If a chip reset occurs, actual SRAM contents will not reflect the most recent write
request (i.e. after a "warm" chip reset, the SRAM does not reflect the last write operation).
Any software that checks SRAM contents after reset must take this into account. Two
identical writes to a location guarantee that the data will be present after a Reset.

What does it mean. and what did he mean by **CPU stalls** and **back to back writes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **write-back** mechanism is a method usually used to guarantee the consistency of the data in memories in a multi-agent system (multi-core systems but also with DMAC - controller of hard disks - for instance). In this case is meant to avoid writing data in the RAM in case it's required in short time from the CPU.

It means that the data is not immediately written to the memory, but held in a register until anyone requests it. It's the alternative to the **write-through** policy, in which every time a write-to-RAM instruction is called for data, it's written directly to the RAM.

It prevents CPU stalls (that are clock cycles in which the CPU is waiting) because the result of the instruction is saved in the register for future access, and it's written to the memory only if needed (another "write" instruction requesting the buffer, that has to be emptied); so you don't need to save into (and load from) RAM a value that is requested in the next instruction.

In this way the content of the RAM is not always up-to-date, so it shows a trick to guarantee that a certain data is written before a reset.

Answer (score 0):

The top writing speed of the CPU is higher than the SRAM can handle. This can be solved by stalling (halting) the CPU untill a write is completed, but this would slow the CPU down. Instead the write action can be stored in a buffer and handled by the SRAM at its own speed. The CPU can now continue executing instructions. Of course the CPU must still be stalled if it attempts a next write action before the write buffer has been written to SRAM. (Instead of a single entry the write buffer can be a queue. Reads actions by the CPU must of course check whether they are reading an address that is in the write buffer or queue.)

The ARM7 seems to use a single writeback buffer, but the text in the manual is not 100% clear about when the actual SRAM write occurs. It suggests that it occurs only when a next CPU write takes place, which would IMO be silly: its only profit would be to eliminate a second consequtive write to the same address with the same data.

CPU stalls == halting the CPU because it must wait for something to complete before it can continue. 'Something' can be many things, like memory read or write, internal (pipelined) operation, result of a previous operation becoming available, etc.

back to back writes == in this context is seems to mean two consequtive writes to the same address.

Comment: In fact, writeback is usually used when more than one agent have access to memory, in order to write buffered data in case the other agent requires it. In this case I think that the mechanism is to empty the buffer before storing the new data (that is probably to be written somewhere else)

Comment: True, but not relevant to this case.

Comment: I think that the use of more than one buffer is more complicated, because it requires addressing, and shifting or managing the "oldness" of data...the second sentence should be relevant, isn't it?

Comment: I was referring to you mentioning "more than one agent". That is not the case here.

Comment: You're dight, it was just to add context to the answer, hopefully making it clear

Comment: I am afraid that in this case such context only confuses the matter. Blame NXP for using the term "write-back buffer" in a less usual context.